# Loop through file and make every word a variable?

Tags: bash, osx

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1923.12.312. Nikl
12391.123.123 Jo
12398123.123912 Ad
```

I am trying to loop through this file, and make `1923.12.312.` `variable1`, and `Nikl` `variable2` then use those in an echo command. Then it should continue and make `12391.123.123` `variable1` and `Jo` `variable2` and echo those etc.

So far, this is what I've done:

```
while read p
do 
variable1="$(awk '{print $1}')"
variable2="$(awk '{print $2}')"
echo "if [ \"\$STATUS\" == \"$variable1\" ]
then
vem=\"$variable2\"
fi"
done saker.txt
```

And that's supposed to put out:

```
if [ "$STATUS" == "1923.12.312." ]
then
vem="NIKL"
fi
```

etc. But it doesn't, instead, this is the output

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print $2)
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ syntax error
if [ "STATUS" == "12391.123.123
12398123.123912" ]
then
vem=""
fi
```

I also tried ditching the variables and did this instead:

```
while read p
do 
echo "if [ \"\$STATUS\" == \"`awk '{print $1}'`\" ]
then
vem=\"`awk '{print $2}'`\"
fi"
done saker.txt
```

But it produced the same result.

Comment: @don_crissti I didn't see that typo actually, but my last command doesn't have it, and it still doesn't work. `while read` was a recommendation from a stackoverflow user. What is better to use for processing text files then? (In your opinion)

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks, that did work. Why? To generate a script. The script I am using regularly needs to be updated with the information from `saker.txt`.

Comment: Related (and @DisplayName, please read this) : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/135943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using shell

If we use the ability of read to separate lines into variables and it is quite easy:

```
while read var1 var2
do
    echo "if [ \"\$status\" == \"$var1\" ]
then
vem=\"$var2\"
fi"
done <saker.txt
```

This produces:

```
if [ "$status" == "1923.12.312." ]
then
vem="Nikl"
fi
if [ "$status" == "12391.123.123" ]
then
vem="Jo"
fi
if [ "$status" == "12398123.123912" ]
then
vem="Ad"
fi
```

#### Using awk:

This awk command uses a single `printf` command:

```
$ awk '{printf "if [ \"$status\" == \"%s\" ]\nthen\nvem=\"%s\"\nfi\n",$1,$2}' saker.txt
if [ "$status" == "1923.12.312." ]
then
vem="Nikl"
fi
if [ "$status" == "12391.123.123" ]
then
vem="Jo"
fi
if [ "$status" == "12398123.123912" ]
then
vem="Ad"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

It is my STRONG suspicion that you shouldn't be running a script to update your script at all.  Instead, you should just call `awk` from within your original script, and get the data you need that way.  Then `saker.txt` could simply be used as a config file (which it is) to change the behavior of your script, (instead of using it to change the output of your script-making-script).

I have very limited data on your script, obviously, but what it looks like is that you are using `saker.txt` as a lookup table to set a variable in your script.

Specifically, the script snippet:

```
if [ "$STATUS" == "1923.12.312." ]
then
vem="Nikl"
fi
if [ "$STATUS" == "12391.123.123" ]
then
vem="Jo"
fi
if [ "$STATUS" == "12398123.123912" ]
then
vem="Ad"
fi
```

can be functionally reproduced with an inline awk script as follows:

```
vem=$( awk -v status="$STATUS" '$1 == status { printf "%s", $2 ; exit }' saker.txt )
```

This answers "How can I set a variable in `bash` based on looking up another variable's value in a file?" which is what it seems you're trying to accomplish by running your script-to-update-your-script.

There are caveats, of course, such as "What if the value of `$STATUS` isn't listed in `saker.txt` at all?"  "What if it's listed twice?"  "How can I set a default value for `vem`?"  But you still have all those caveats, and moreso, with a script-updating-script.

---

EDIT: If you want to allow spaces in the value of `vem` as given in the `saker.txt` file, you're better off using something else for a delimiter, such as a tab:

```
$ cat saker.txt
1923.12.312.    Nikl
12391.123.123   Jo
12398123.123912 Ad
```

Then use the following version of the `awk` one-liner:

```
vem=$( awk -Ft -v status="$STATUS" '$1 == status { printf "%s", $2 ; exit }' saker.txt )
```

A caveat about tab delimiters: Be sure you don't use *more than one* tab.  Unlike `awk`'s default "whitespace delimited" handling, when you explicitly set the delimiter as a TAB only, *each* tab is counted as a delimiter regardless of whether there is any text between the tabs.  So `10000<tab><tab>John` will be regarded as THREE fields: "10000", "" (empty field), and "John".

Comment: I figured this out later. I am just running a script from there. Now my problem is that sometimes I need `||` because multiple `$STATUS` variables can match a single `$vem`, but that's another story.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the bit about needing an OR operator.  Do you mean that you might have multiple "status" numbers that associate to the same name?  If so, why not just have multiple lines in the `saker.txt` file, one for each status?  If you do it that way the awk one-liner above would work exactly the same.

Comment: Never mind, I thought wrong.

Comment: I tried a bunch of things but I couldn't get it to work with `$STATUS` including a space? (Should have specified that in question).

Comment: You'll have to decide on the format you want for your lookup table.  Whether you use `awk` or `read`, there has to be some kind of delimiter.  (Unless of course you hack it together so that the *first* space on a line is read as a delimiter, and the rest of the line up to the newline is a value even if it includes spaces, but that would be hacky in the extreme.)  Comma separated or tab separated would both be workable; just a matter of preference.  Updating answer now.

Comment: I'm quite curious by now what your script is *doing* with the value of `vem` after it's set, and where you get the value of `STATUS` from.  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32340/discussion-between-wildcard-and-displayname).